# Create seed data from sql script

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, orm, mapping

I'm using ORM in my project. Currently seed data is taken from sql scripts but I would like to create seed data basing on my c# code. For example, I have sql:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[State] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[State] ([Id], [Code], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'AL', N'Alabama')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[State] ([Id], [Code], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'AK', N'Alaska')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[State] OFF
```

And instead of it I want to have a string:

```
new List<State> 
{
    new State { Id = 1, Code = "AL", Name = "Alabama" },
    new State { Id = 2, Code = "AK", Name = "Alaska" }
};
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For INSERT statements (as you said you need seed) you can create helper method like this:

```
public static List<State> ParseSqlScript(string sqlScriptPath)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(sqlScriptPath))
        {
            var sqlScript = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var pattern = @"INSERT INTO \[dbo\].\[State\] \(\[Id\], \[Code\], \[Name\]\) VALUES (\(.*?\))";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            var matches = regex.Matches(sqlScript);
            var states = new List<State>();
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var values = match.Groups[1].Value.Split(new [] { '(', ',',' ',')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var id = int.Parse(values[0]);
                var code = values[1].Substring(2, values[1].Length - 3);
                var name = values[2].Substring(2, values[2].Length - 3);
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    var state = new State() { Id = id, Code = code, Name = name };
                    states.Add(state);
                }
            }

            return states;
        }
    }
```

If you also need other CRUD statements you will probably need to get acquainted with some SQL Parser, maybe the Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I want. You save my day

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code, I assume you are working with entity framework:

```
List<State> states = new List<State>()  
            {  
                new State { Id = 1, Code = "AL", Name = "Alabama" },
                new State { Id = 2, Code = "AK", Name = "Alaska" }  

            }; 

StateDBEntities context = new StateDBEntities(); 
foreach (State state in states)  
            {  
                context.State.Add(state);  
            }  

            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that is not that I have wanted. My goal is to get 'List<State> states 'somehow from the sql script

Answer (score 0):

```
List<State> states = new List<State>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("conn_string"))
    {
        string query = "SELECT Id, Code, Name FROM State";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    State state =  new State { Id = (int)reader["Id"], Code = reader["Code"].ToString(), Name = reader["Name"].ToString() };
                    states.Add(state);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Call the select query(here I'm writing the query, but it should be avoided, you can use Stored Procedure). Get all columns using `ExecuteReader` and add all the rows to list one by one.